# Изменения status bar с помощью onmouseover

Tags: javascript, html

Добрый день,
моей задачей является замена содержимого статус бара браузера при наведении курсора на ссылку, т.е. место url должен выводится произвольный текст. Использую данный метод:

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="window.status='текст'">Главная</a>
```

Однако, статус изменяется только при клике на ссылку. Как реализовать замену при наводке?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ololo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href='#' onmouseover="doThis();">Главная</a>
        <script>
            function doThis(){
               window.status='текст';
               alert( window.status);//чтобы уж наверняка
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: сильно...

     //чтобы уж наверняка

Comment: @altvirus, тоесть вы вынесли тот же кусочек кода в отдельную функцию и это должно работать как-то иначе?

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что использовать `window.status` можно только в "узкоспециализированых" задачах, т.к. это работает исключительно в браузере Opera, и то, только если этого не запрещено в настройках. Лучше менять значение `document.title` — тогда будет работать во всех современных браузерах.

```
<a href='#' onmouseover="document.title='test'">Главная</a>
```